# Include drafts in internal link dialog

Tags: draft, workflow, linking

Ok, so I'm doing a new project and we're going to be using Wordpress as a magazine CMS. In some cases we'll have a cluster of articles about a topic and it will be natural to link from one article to another. So, here we are in final edit in WP.
We want to add a link from one draft article to another draft article in the cluster, but the target article hasn't been published, so WP doesn't show it in the `Link to Existing Content` box. Sure, I can get the shortlink for the draft of the article I want to link to, but then I need to open that tab, get the shortlink (or the draft's slug), move back to the post that I want to link from, add the link. Doing this occasionally is fine but as a constant task it's crappy workflow.

Now, we can simply publish and then hurriedly go through the articles and link things, but that's suboptimal. I can't imagine all of the magazines and other sites that do periodical publishing with WP do that though. I'll play with Editflow to see if it has a way to deal with this, but does anyone know of a way to link from one draft to another and have the link be correct when they're both published?

And yes, I know I can link things up after publishing. See 'crappy workflow'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/65271/73).

We have to hook into `check_ajax_referer` to address the internal linking feature only. Then we register an action for `pre_get_posts` to extend the search to drafts and pending posts.

We will still get no pretty permalinks, because they are excluded in `get_permalink`. So we register a filter for that too and ask WordPress again for a permalink, but with a faked post status.

As code:

```
add_action( 'check_ajax_referer', 'internal_links_for_drafts' );

/**
 * Extend search for internal links to 'draft' and 'pending' statuses.
 *
 * @wp-hook check_ajax_referer
 * @wp-hook pre_get_posts
 * @param string|WP_Query $var
 * @return boolean|void
 */
function internal_links_for_drafts( $var )
{
    if ( 'check_ajax_referer' === current_filter() && 'internal-linking' === $var )
        return add_action( 'pre_get_posts', __FUNCTION__ );

    // now we are in the 'pre_get_posts' action.
    $var->set( 'post_status', array( 'publish', 'pending', 'draft' ) );
    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', __FUNCTION__ );
    add_filter( 'post_link', 'draft_permalink', 10, 2 );
}
/**
 * Get permalink for drafts and pending posts.
 *
 * Dangerous, because their title can still change.
 *
 * @param  string $permalink
 * @param  object $post
 * @return string
 */
function draft_permalink( $permalink, $post )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // swap status temporary
    $original_status   = $post->post_status;
    $post->post_status = 'publish';
    $url               = get_permalink( $post );
    $post->post_status = $original_status;

    return $url;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I could have hacked the core file that builds this dialog of course, but that's a Bad Thing To Do. This works well, much appreciated.

Comment: Shame this isn't a plugin rather than a hack.